# add additional info to pages

Tags: wordpress

I have pages in the wordpress (duh) :)

when i edit the page:

the pages contains some info
and some additional info with links

these **additonal info** i want to wrap it in a div container so the css display it differently. its not a good approach to do it in de wysiwyg editor.

so my question is there a better way to add additional info and link this to a page.
so when you are navigating through pages, the page info and the additional info are displayed?

can i hand code it?
or I need to install some plugins?

I dont know where the look.
Need some guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply achieve that with **custom fields**:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

Or with one of the many plugins that help you adding custom boxes like **More Fields**:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/more-fields/

Hope it helps